# knockout.js bound property value gets set to null if dropdown is empty

Tags: knockout.js, properties, breeze, durandal

Using Durandal 2.0 framework.  I have an object property (contactID) bound to a select element (list of contacts).  I am retrieving the object from the DB using breeze.js.  When I retrieve the data, the contactID has a value of 5 which is a FK to the contact table.  If the dropdown that this property is bound to is EMPTY, the object property changes from 5 to null.  Is that by design?  In this case I can't get the values for the dropdown before I get the value of ContactID.  thanks

Comment: sounds like you are running into this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125788/knockoutjs-losing-previous-value-when-loading-options-after-value/20136627#20136627. Some solutions there for how to prepopulate your field with a value prior to your options being available.

Comment: I saw those.  the problems is the same, but those solutions are not working for my project.  Between the time the data is returned, and I have access to the object in my VM, Durandal/Breeze/Knockout does its magic and the value is gone.  I would like to save the value and then "re-set" it after the dropdown is populated.  But I can't even get to it to save it.  The value is cleared very soon after coming back from the server and I do not know where to intercept it. There's a key field coming back in this query that is used to populate the dropdown.  Right now i'm just querying twice.